# Entity Framework Core - Composite and Foreign Keys as Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core. I have a class with 3 columns primary key, and this is used on other class and add 1 new primary key (4 primary key) How to create the relationship on `OnModelCreating`?

```
public class Head
{
    public string Id1 { get; set; }
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
    public string Id3 { get; set; }

    public List<Details> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public string Id1 { get; set; } -- foreign key and primary key
    public string Id2 { get; set; } -- foreign key and primary key
    public string Id3 { get; set; } -- foreign key and primary key
    public string Id4 { get; set; } -- primary key
}
```

I hope help me to resolve this problem using EF Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `OnModelCreating` method you can do something like this,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Head>()
        .HasMany(header => header.Details)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(details => new { details.Id1, details.Id2, details.Id3 });
}
```

Here `HasMany()` method  and `WithMany()` methods are used to configure a many-to-many relationship between the Head and Details entitites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have the error: CollectionCollectionBuilder<Details, Head>' does not contain a definition for 'HasForeignKey' and no accessible extension method 'HasForeignKey' accepting a first argument of type 'CollectionCollectionBuilder<Details, Head>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @Arthur486 try to add `public Head Head { get; set; }` to Details class